# Create voice recognition app

Tags: iphone, android

I need to develop an App witch detects voice when it´s running (not what are they saying, just if someone speaks) and if so, I need to launch an especific mp3 from my sd.

I never developed for android/iphone but I need to especify my boss in how many hours it could be done.

Is there any easy way for voice recognition? and... I think that the answear could be yes but, is ther a way to listen a specified mp3 from my code?

(no plataform specified yet, it could be android or iphone)

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659726/detect-the-beginning-of-a-sound-or-voice-in-android) question. It might help a bit. if you got back something valid from the google servers, then you could cause it play an MP3, I suppose.

EDIT: Also, it's important to remember that android phones don't do the "voice recognizing" themselves. The sound is streamed to Google servers (like a phone call) and the servers "recognize" what you're saying, and send that back to the phone.