# clap sound detection in android

Tags: android-asynctask, android-audiorecord

I've searched StackOverflow and the web for many questions on whistle detection, etc, and many people did explain as much as they could as to how they can go about detecting their stuff.

[Detect Whistle sound in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767476/detect-whistle-sound-in-android)

[Detect the beginning of a sound or voice in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659726/detect-the-beginning-of-a-sound-or-voice-in-android)

But I don't get how to detect "**Jack Hammer sound count**" in android app?
Required counter can count atleast 33 strike/sec(or 2000 strike/min).

Can any one suggest some solution?

This is my doInBackground method

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(AudioCilpListener... listeners) {

        if (listeners.length == 0) {

            return 0;

        }
        AudioCilpListener listener = listeners[0];        
        AudioClipRecorder recorder = new AudioClipRecorder(listener, this);
//        boolean heard = false;
        int count = 0;        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try {

                count = recorder.startRecordingForTime(30,
                                AudioClipRecorder.RECORDER_SAMPLERATE_CD,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                break;

            } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {

                // failed to setup, sleep and try again
                // if still can't set it up, just fail
                ie.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
        //collect the audio
        return count;

    }
```

Comment: what is your problem? did you try and recreate those whislty/soudnstart apps / that source code? And what happened then? WHere are you stuk: do you have anything that can detect one strike, but are you having trouble with the speed? Is the speed ok, but can you not make the app? what is going on?

Comment: Till now I can detect 500 strike/minute. But I need help to achieve the resolution.

Comment: then show your code, or part of it. Without knowing what you are allready doing, we're just going to throw out random stuff, aren't we? How can we see what you can approve if we don't see what you are doing?

Comment: I just dont want any code from u guys, Ionly need some suggestions.

Comment: See I've edited my ques and post my doInBackground method stuff of AsyncTask class

And also if u really want to help then see this post also:

[link] http://stackoverflow.com/q/18463765/2563740

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer the book named "Android Sensor Programming 2012".

In Part-3 Chapter-14 "Using the Microphone", you will get all the relevant details

Comment: can u tell me which one is better for my case mediarecorder class or audiorecord class ...??

Comment: According to your counter resolution u must use the audio record class method...it saves time in file IO as compared to media recorder class.

Comment: Dear could you please post a snippet?

Comment: Man you guys seem very knowledgible